# How to append to Rose Trees in Scala

Tags: scala, tree, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I'm in need of a Rose Tree data structure like `scalaz.Tree` or the following:

```
case class Tree[A](root: A, children: Stream[Tree[A]])
```

However I'm having a hard time understanding how to write a function for appending nodes. In general, I understand that appending a node involves rebuilding the tree, and doing that with immutable data structures requires recursive functions, but I just haven't been able to put it all together. I did see [Scala: Tree Insert Tail Recursion With Complex Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511433/scala-tree-insert-tail-recursion-with-complex-structure) but since that involves binary trees, I didn't quite grasp how to implement it for a multi-way tree.

Traditionally, I would implement this mutably using Array or such. Is there some book or resource that I should read to understand functional data structures more? Or is there some example code that could be recommended for me to read over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't obvious what are your requirements for "appending nodes". You can do it in the trivial way, inserting the second node as a first child:

```
def append[A](tree1: Tree[A], tree2: Tree[A]) = tree1 match {
  case Tree(root, children) => Tree(root, tree2 #:: children)
}
```

If that's not what you want, can you provide an example?

> Is there some book or resource that I should read to understand functional data structures more? Or is there some example code that could be recommended for me to read over?

The standard recommendation is [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). The code examples aren't in Scala, but it should be easy enough to translate the knowledge.